# Identifying Correct Power Cable Extension

Tags: transformer, identification, electrical

I have the following power cable for a projector:

[image: example power cable]
I need either an extension for the part that goes in to the projector (with the yellow pin) or a whole new power cable and block with a longer cable on that side of the block.

Does the circled yellow pin input plug have a specific name? I've tried searching for extension cables (female of that pin, back to male again) but can't get the search terms correct for relevant results.

Are there any potential issues with that? I'd be looking for an extension of around 5 meters (or an alternative charge cable which comes with 5 meters as standard).

Edit: Also just to clarify, I realise using a power extension on the plug side would be easier, but I need the block to be further away from the projector, so that's not a viable option. The projector's being mounted on the ceiling and I don't want to place the power block above the ceiling tiles.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks to me like one of the common laptop charger plugs.

Comment: @Hearth I agree it is the same type of block and cable you'd see for a laptop, music keyboard, desktop speakers, and the like. But I'm trying to identify a proper name for the thin cable/pin that goes into a device to find a female>male extension cable. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is specifically a laptop; I've never seen this type with the yellow tip and Φ-shaped hole for anything other than laptops.

Comment: Hi @Hearth - Ah I see what you meant now. The Asus projector came newly boxed with a yellow tip Φ-shaped pin, so I'm confident it's the correct style of cable, block, and pin. Thanks.

Comment: Extending the dc side by 5m may cause voltage drop issues and that will affect the charging algorithms... I would get the mains side extended.

Comment: The correct term is "barrel jack" and plug.

Comment: What @SolarMike said. I don't think any "charging" is involved here, but extending DC will indeed cause voltage drop and potentially result in faulty operation. Also any problems with 3.5A wiring are potentially more dangerous than good quality AC extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barrel Connector Power cable. Watch out though as adding length adds resistance and could cause a change in output power.

Something like [CA-2209](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tensility-international-corp/CA-2209/CP-2209-ND/1129472)

[image]